# Can't connect docker python app to selenium standalone

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cpanel

I have a Docker container for python project which I'm using to do some scraping with selenium. The connection was successfull locally. but when I ran the docker in my cpanel server, the connection couldn't be established.

My app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['JSONIFY_TIMEOUT'] = 120

    @app.route('/test_connection')
    def test_connection():
        capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://{host}:4450/wd/hub',
                                      desired_capabilities=capabilities)
            driver.quit()
            return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'Connection successful'})
        except WebDriverException as e:
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': str(e)})
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I'm testing on postman, so when testing on localhost, connection is successfull, but when run on the cpanel server, the request returns "Could not get response"

I tried openning the selenium url in the browser, it opened, and I can see I have chrome stereotype there
[screenshot of selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBOGk.png)

this is my Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN pip3 install flask requests selenium selenium_stealth
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN export FLASK_APP=app.py
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I tried approving the ports on the cPanel server "4450"
I couldn't use port "4444" because there is already another project running on cpanel with port "4444"
this is the new selenium standalone I'm trying to connect to. (when connecting to it in localhost it wroks fine)

```
selenium/standalone-chrome:latest "/opt/bin/entry_poin…" 5900/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7900->7900/tcp, :::7900->7900/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4450->4444/tcp, :::4450->4444/tcp
```

This is the old selenium that is already being used by another project

```
selenium/hub:3.14.0 "/opt/bin/entry_poin…" 0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp, :::4445->4444/tcp
```

the above lines are displayed in response for the command "docker ps"